Adding I am policy to code pipe line stage
Good day,
I have a pipeline and I am adding an integration test stage. My integration test creates an S3 client as such :
const result = await s3Client.uploadObject({
           bucket: bucket,
           objectKey: objectKey,
           object: JSON.stringify(data),
       });

This works fine on the local machine but in code pipeline it fails with access denied. I have added the PutObject policy for the bucket, I have also added kms Decrypt and Encrypt, but I am still getting this in my integration test stage.
Please if you can guide me in the right direction.

kms:GenerateDataKey is also needed
